# Background Images Paths are Changed when CSS Aggregation is On

Tags: css-js-aggregation, theming

I have a Drupal 7 site with and Adaptives Themes subtheme enabled and set as default. I was recreating the Drupal 6 site in Drupal 7 on a subdomain and have recently transferred it over. My site has worked any problems until I turned on the aggregator for the CSS and JS files.

When my CSS files are compressed, the background images paths are not only absolute, `background-image: url(images/relative_to_CSS_file.png)` => `background-image: url(/subdomain/sites/all/themes/theme_name/css/images/relative_to_CSS_file.png)`, it adds the subdomain in the path. Instead, I would like to just remove the subdomain.

I have flushed the caches a few times, but this problem persists. How do I update these files?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you [@jessehs](https://www.drupal.org/u/jessehs) from Drupal.org.

His solution, which worked for me, is the following:

> Long story short, the problem was that Adaptive Theme appears to be
>   doing a "pre-caching caching" of the compiled CSS files in the
>   sites/default/files/adaptivetheme/ directory.
>
> The way to get the aggregated files to actually build is to clear all
>   caches and immediately save the theme's settings form at
>   /admin/appearance/settings/[themename], then do another cache clear,
>   just for good measure.

Also included at the source is a helper module that will flush these files when you flush the cache.

<sub>Source: https://www.drupal.org/node/1995938</sub>

Comment: [AdvAgg](https://www.drupal.org/project/advagg/) handles this use case out of the box; it calls at_core_settings_submit for you.